# How to write sinon tests where third part api's are concerned

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I am attempting to test geocode.js which has only one function :

// geocode.js

```
const googleApiClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
  key: CONFIG.googleApis.key
});

const poll = zipcode => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

     googleApiClient.geocode({
        address: zipcode
      }, function(err, response) {
           resolve(response.json.results); // This is line 22
     });

   });

};

module.exports = {poll}
```

so i have setup my mocha environment and installed sinon. I can't figure out how to stub the googleApiClient functionality.

I don't actually want to make any kind of external call during the test.

```
 //geocode.spec.js
describe('geocode', function(){
   before(function(){

     //HOW DO I STUB googleApiClient ?
     sinon.stub ...

   })

});
```

Comment: Alternative POV: Don't mock `googleApiClient`, instead pass a client to `poll` as an argument. You can then create any plain old object with a `geocode` method instead of having to monkey-patch the `googleApiClient` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a PITA, because `createClient` returns a plain object each time, and not a class that you can stub.

Nonetheless, I came up with this:

```
const chai   = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const sinon  = require('sinon');

// This allows us to `expect` on Sinon properties.
chai.use(require('sinon-chai'));

// Load the Google Maps module.
const googleMaps = require('@google/maps');

// Create a dummy client.
const googleApiClient = googleMaps.createClient({ key : 'foo' });

// Stub `googleMaps.createClient` so it always returns the dummy client.
let createClientStub = sinon.stub(googleMaps, 'createClient').returns(googleApiClient);

// Load the code to be tested. This has to be done _after_ stubbing `createClient`.
const poll = require('./geocode.js').poll;

// The test.
describe('geocode', function(){
  let stub;

  // For each test, stub the `geocode` function.
  beforeEach(function() {
    stub = sinon.stub(googleApiClient, 'geocode');
  });

  // After each test, restore it to its original.
  afterEach(function() {
    stub.restore();
  });

  it('should call `googleApiClient.geocode` with the correct zipcode', function() {
    // This means that `googleApiClient.geocode()` will call the first function
    // argument that it gets passed, which is the callback function that
    // resolves the promise.
    stub.yields(null, { json : { results : 'foo' } });

    // Now we call the function under test, pass it a zipcode, and check if 
    // googleApiClient.geocode() got called with the correct argument.
    const ZIPCODE = '90210';
    return poll(ZIPCODE).then(zipcode => {
      expect(stub).to.be.calledWith({ address: ZIPCODE });
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: @robertkley  Thank you for the detailed explanation. This greatly helps. However I am unable to understand why do I keep getting this error:  ** 1) geocode service should call `googleApiClient.geocode` with the correct zipcode:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
      at app/services/geocode.service.js:22:25
**

Comment: @BubbleTrouble that depends on what's on line 22 of the file `app/services/geocode.service.js`.

Comment: @robertkley I have updated my question above to reflect what's on line 22

Comment: @BubbleTrouble ah okay, the callback to `geocode` expects that the arguments are of a particular format. I editted my answer, the only change is how `stub.yields()` gets called (it reflects the arguments that the callback will receive, so a fake "error" and "response"). However, it does go to show that your implementation is lacking error handling and handling invalid responses (but that's why you're testing, of course).

Answer (score 0):

**Here's how you can do it**

I am gonna show it by an example of stubbing of ***HTTP call*** API:

```
const httpCallStub = sinon.stub(HTTP, 'call');
const callback = sinon.spy();

// test case block

it('Testing function which has HTTP call API', function () {
  response.data = {
    // dummy api response
  };
  httpCallStub.yields(null, response);
  functionWhichhasThisHTTPCallAPI(callback);
  expect(callback.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
});
```

**So what's happening in that code**

1. basically when you yield stub, it passes those arguments when that function actually gets called
2. so when I yield HTTP get API, so when in test case it comes, sinon doesn't call HTTP API but passes those 2 arguments as response of that API call

Let me know if it's clear.